# Doing a Full Outer Join with Derived tables - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am having trouble with a full outer join on two tables, the sql i am using is as follows:

```
SELECT
  a.sryear,
  b.reqyear,
  a.mid,
  b.description,
  sum(a.kmq + b.rmq) as sum 
FROM
  (select
    EXTRACT(YEAR 
  FROM
    t.date) AS srYear,
    m.materialid as mid,
    m.description,
    sum(km.quantity) as kmq 
  FROM
    kit k,
    kitmaterial km,
    materials m,
    service s,
    transaction t 
  WHERE
    t.serviceid=s.serviceid 
    AND s.kitid=k.kitid 
    AND k.kitid=km.kitid 
    AND km.materialid=m.materialid 
  GROUP BY
    srYear,
    m.materialid 
  ORDER BY
    srYear,
    m.materialid) as a FULL 
OUTER JOIN
  , (
    SELECT
      EXTRACT(YEAR 
    FROM
      r.datecreated) AS reqYear,
      m.materialid as mid,
      m.description as description,
      sum(rm.quantity) as rmq 
    FROM
      requisitionmaterial rm,
      materials m,
      requisition r 
    WHERE
      rm.materialid=m.materialid 
      AND r.requisitionid=rm.requisitionid 
    GROUP BY
      reqYear,
      m.materialid 
    ORDER BY
      reqYear,
      m.materialid
  ) as b 
    ON a.mid=b.mid 
    AND a.sryear=b.reqyear;
```

Any assistance rendered will be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: It's too complicated. can you minimize sql query, only necessary column, table would be appreciated. and describe what's your problem. what do you want to printed

Answer (score 1):

under the condition that  inline view `a` and `b` works as you expected, there is one problem.

```
SELECT
  ....
  sum(a.kmq + b.rmq) as sum
```

`SUM()` is aggregation function. So can't be used without `GROUP BY`. did you mean this?

```
SELECT
  ....
  a.kmq + b.rmq as `sum`
```

otherwise, you should use GROUP BY with some column